# All of human knowledge — in one place

Tags: technology

What would be the effects of a database of EVERYTHING? I mean everything humans have gathered and researched in our time on this planet. This database would include television, magazines, books, newspapers, the Internet, and ALL of the information that is in ALL of our minds. Basically, all of this information would be easily navigable and would be sorted by topic. What could this be used for?

Comment: Reddit, only in database form? Is this a physical one place, or can it be "one place" like Google?

Comment: this is a physical place in one location. if you want to access this information, you need to go to this specific location.

Comment: is this the only source for all knowledge? because its going to get crowded when 7 billion people turn up wanting to know how to plant crops, turn cattle into food, make cloth... (and get their reruns of M*A*S*H)

Comment: No, this is kind of a secondary resource. All information that we have currently is still here. This is just a place where all of it comes together, and is sorted so it is extremely easy to find any possible information. Note that this database also includes the observations of humans thousands of years ago, as well as any information they may have collected in their lifetime.

Comment: Why can't we add a network interface and add it to the internet?

Comment: well, if that's the case, it's only going to be interesting to historians because the effort of going there isn't going to be worth it for almost everyone else.

Comment: really? I mean, you have literally everything right there. Don't the benefits of visiting it far outweigh the negatives or costs?

Comment: You might be interested in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Library_of_Babel.

Comment: As far as I understand it, that's more or less how Warhammer 40K Mechanicus started : gather all knowledge in one place, then when civilisation blows up - making the delocalized fragment out of reach -, the automated library system gets more and more corrupted and you have to turn to rotes and ceremonial to maintain what you have managed to save.

Comment: @PipperChip Like [this](https://archive.org/details/2015_reddit_comments_corpus)?  (It's all of the public reddit comments from 2007 to July 2015 or so).

Comment: Eventually barbaric, uneducated hordes will destroy it, as Hypatia's story may attest: https://vimeo.com/70473922

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I thought we had something resembling this already: the Internet.

Okay, if you mean literally ALL human knowledge ever obtained, does that include knowledge that in the real world is secret or has been lost? Like, somehow this includes information that is presently only in people's heads? All the information acquired in ancient times? Etc?

As @amacb says, if there's no security on this, then there would be immediate disaster. Any nut case could get plans for an atom bomb and instructions on how to find the necessary materials, or formula for chemical weapons, etc.

Less dramatically but still pretty bad, criminals could find the identities and addresses of defenseless old people with lots of cash or other valuables in their homes. Information on undetectable poisons or how to destroy evidence. Etc.

Or maybe not. If it has all human knowledge, then presumably the authorities can tap in to get lists of everyone who is plotting a crime or terrorist attack.

But then that would mean that tyrants would know every plot against them and could promptly have all dissenters arrested and executed.

On the plus side: It would surely be a great aid to all sorts of scientific research. There'd be no need to duplicate effort or chase blind alleys that others had already explored. You could find research that is relevant to yours but not obviously so, like research published in obscure journals, or which was directed at another field but impinges on yours, like research intended find new fuels makes a chemical discovery that would be useful in curing lymphoma if only the medical researchers knew about it. Etc.

In people's daily lives, it would be easy to find lost relatives. People could find the best deal on any product they want to buy or sell. They could find the best available job.

Many old mysteries would be solved, from, What happened to Jimmy Hoffa? to, Was there really an Atlantis?

Which suddenly makes me think to ask, Are we assuming that all the information in this repository is true, and that everyone is 100% confidant that it is true? Because if so it could presumably also tell you if Jesus really came back from the dead or if an angel really appeared to Mohamed and so on. Next to those sort of questions, things like, Did President Obama really not know about the [Fast and Furious scandal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ATF_gunwalking_scandal) until he heard it on the news?, seem pretty insignificant.

Answer (score 5):

> Dwan Ev ceremoniously soldered the final connection with gold. The
>   eyes of a dozen television cameras watched him and the subether bore
>   throughout the universe a dozen pictures of what he was doing.
>
> He straightened and nodded to Dwar Reyn, then moved to a position
>   beside the switch that would complete the contact when he threw it.
>   The switch that would connect, all at once, all of the monster
>   computing machines of all the populated planets in the universe --
>   ninety-six billion planets -- into the supercircuit that would connect
>   them all into one supercalculator, one cybernetics machine that would
>   combine all the knowledge of all the galaxies.
>
> Dwar Reyn spoke briefly to the watching and listening trillions. Then
>   after a moment's silence he said, "Now, Dwar Ev."
>
> Dwar Ev threw the switch. There was a mighty hum, the surge of power
>   from ninety-six billion planets. Lights flashed and quieted along the
>   miles-long panel.
>
> Dwar Ev stepped back and drew a deep breath. "The honor of asking the
>   first question is yours, Dwar Reyn."
>
> "Thank you," said Dwar Reyn. "It shall be a question which no single
>   cybernetics machine has been able to answer."
>
> He turned to face the machine. "Is there a God?"
>
> The mighty voice answered without hesitation, without the clicking of
>   a single relay.
>
> "Yes, now there is a God."  Sudden fear flashed on the face of Dwar
>   Ev. He leaped to grab the switch.  A bolt of lightning from the
>   cloudless sky struck him down and fused the switch shut.

(Fredric Brown, "Answer")

http://www.roma1.infn.it/~anzel/answer.html

Answer (score 2):

If **all** knowledge was accessible by **everyone**, a major problem with this "world database" would occur if this "library" was not heavily guarded:

Suppose you are a terrorist who wants to see US to be demolished. If there was a place you could go to access any **kind of knowledge** (e.g. construction of nuclear bombs, specifics on how remote-controlled weapons are operated...), it would become a major target for these organizations. If a group managed to steal blueprints for, say, the specifics of an attack drone, they would almost definitely be able to exploit a weakness in it. (A couple years ago in real life, some people in Iran were able to generate false GPS signals for a US Drone, and essentially override controls) Who knows what would happen if they were able to access a database with information on **every single military drone, weapon, warship, tank...**

---

The point is, the centralization of all knowledge into a single place would draw all kinds of attention from terrorist organizations and even other countries. If knowledge is dispersed all around the world (like it is in real life), there is no central target where everything is.

Comment: true, true. couldn't this kind of database also be used for beneficial purposes, like creating new medicines or spacecraft? then again, we are humans, so we are unlikely to play together nicely...

Comment: It could, but the consequences would be disastrous. Every time someone accessed any part of this database could be a person who wants to learn how to blow up a nuke in the middle of the US.

Comment: Could this scenario eventually spiral into some nuclear apocalypse?

Comment: Probably it could within a century.

Comment: @fi12, ask [Alfred Nobel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alfred_Nobel) what his intended use for Dynamite was. Regardless of the intention of the creator, the potential for destruction in many scientifically valuable inventions means that all knowledge in the hands of the wrong people (and "everyone" necessarily includes the wrong people) would lead to a catastrophic loss of life.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming a sort complete and accurate Wikipedia with public access + God level Wiki-leaks. Where every government, institutional, and corporate secrets is available for anyone to see.

It would change absolutely nothing. The powers that be would tell us the library is liberal/conservative propaganda and make their own counter-spun libraries. The corporations would make sure patent law prevented anyone from using the public knowledge. Human laziness and lack of interest would prevent mot folks from caring. Academics would still have a chore of correlation and pattern finding and pet theories and misinterpretations. Nobody in power listens to those guys anyhow. Human society is institutional and this database would in all real effects be a better internet and the institutional safeguards against it would be applied to the database.

If you asked this question a century ago the answer would have been the world we have today.

[ I would spend all day reading it so I guess that would be different]

Answer (score 0):

An organization exists that is attempting something similar to what you describe.  It isn't collecting analog knowledge but it is attempting to collect and archive all digital knowledge.

### [The Internet Archive](https://archive.org/index.php)

In it's own words:

> Internet Archive is a non-profit library of millions of free books,
>   movies, software, music, and more.

#### [The Way Back Machine](https://archive.org/web/)

(or [WABAC machine named for the time machine in the cartoon **"Peabody's Improbable History"** from the **Rocky and Bullwinkle Show**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WABAC_machine))

In addition to collecting all of this information digitally, the internet archive has a web crawler that captures and archives snapshots of the internet over time.  Websites can opt out, however, the Internet Archive archives all websites that have not opted out.

With the Wayback machine, you can specify a site (e.g. Google) and time (e.g. 2/29/2000) and see exactly what that website looked like at that time.  BTW, this is the link to the archive of Google from 2/29/2000

#### Size

The Internet Archive statistics looks like this (PetaByte: $PB = 1024 TB = 2^{20} GB$):

> 1. Density: 1.4 PetaBytes / rack
> 2. Power consumption: 3 KW / PetaByte
> 3. No Air Conditioning, instead use excess heat to help heat the
>      building.
> 4. Raw Numbers as of August 2014:
>
>    - 4 data centers, 550 nodes, 20,000 spinning disks
>    - Wayback Machine: 9.6 PetaBytes
>    - Books/Music/Video Collections: 9.8 PetaBytes
>    - Unique data: 18.5 PetaBytes
>    - **Total used storage: 50 PetaBytes**